# How to pass multiple objects to IGListKit Section Controller

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, iglistkit

I'm using IGListStackedSectionController and I want to know how to pass multiple objects to any of given childs.

I have a scenario like this:

```
let sectionController = IGListStackedSectionController(sectionControllers: [
            WorkingRangeSectionController(),
            DisplaySectionController(),
            HorizontalSectionController(),
            ])!
```

Let's say I want to put a dynamic title on the first section, an array of images in the second section and a different array of images on the last section.

How would I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you find out?

Comment: no :( I've created multiple section controllers, not good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't do this. Same object is passed to all subsection controllers.

**Long answer:**

You can combine all necessary data to a class, e.g.:

```
class Model {
    var title = ""
    var images = [UIImage]()
    var otherImages = [UIImage]()
}
```

You also need to implement `IGListDiffable` protocol according to your needs.

There is brief example of `IGListStackedSectionController` in `IGListKit` examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit).

Comment: Worth noting that its totally ok to create objects that act as "grab bags" for other objects. You can take this object and decompose it in sub-section controllers that can pick & choose the properties they need.